# SQL Server Agent - Is there the ability to comment out multiple jobs in a single step?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent job that has a number of separate steps. Within some of these steps I have multiple exec statements that fire off stored procedures to populate tables. My question is this: Is there a means to comment out some of these exec statements? Currently I am deleting lines while working on changes and reinstating them once the changes have been completed. I don't have a test environment to experiment with. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you split the list of EXECs into multiple steps in the same job? That way you can more easily control (even programmatically) which steps fire and which does not?

Comment: I'd like to @RoKa, but I'm stuck with using the current set up. There is a logic to the organisation of the steps, but each step has accumulated more and more jobs which need occasional maintenance.

Comment: A dirty way of doing this might be to manipulate the [command] column in the sysjobsteps table in msdb?  If you post a code sample of your job step, I'll type up an answer below

Comment: Why don't you comment the lines out using `--`, `//` or `/* ... */`?

Comment: Thanks @flo. I've used these in SQL, but was not sure whether they would also work in a SQL Agent step. As I mentioned previously, I cannot test this, as the only SQL Agent we have is in the live environment, so I need to be 100% sure!

Comment: I agree with @flo ... use `/*`  and `*/`

Comment: Thanks @Roka. The SQL Agent step simply has a whole list of exec commands e.g. `exec sp_job1; exec sp_job2;exec sp_job2;` etc

Comment: OK. Thanks @Roka, I'll try the simple SQL comment!

Comment: Many thanks @flo. I really had not seen the "Parse" button in the step window. Doh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script of the job is standard TSQL. You can use comments like `--`, `//` or `/* ... */` to comment out `exec`s you don't want to run.

If you use the Management Studio, you can hit the `Parse` button left of the script to check your syntax.